# String substitution doesn't work in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Given text is the 'C' style structure -

```
    struct mystruct {
        int a[100];
        int b[10*10];
        int c[10*5+(25*2)];
        int d[10^2];
    }
```

Read the text line by line and evaluate the number of elements in each array and re-declare arrays with element count.

Result should be printed as follows :-

```
    struct mystruct {
        int a[100];
        int b[100];
        int c[100];
        int d[100];
    }
```

Following string substitution doesn't work for me -

```
    if ($line =~ m/.*?\[(.*?)\]/) {
        $answer = eval ($1);
        $line =~ s/$1/$answer/g;
    }
```

The substitution did not work and the $line remained unchanged for all evaluated element count.

Comment: $1 contains special chars (*, +) that are interpeted by s///

Comment: Others's solutions are probably smarter, but if you need to match a literal in a regex in the future, you should look at the `\Q` escape or `quotemeta`.

Answer (score 5):

Do the evaluation directly in the substitution:

```
$line =~ s/(?<=\[)   # assert a square bracket behind
           ([^]]*)   # capture string of non-brackets
           (?=\])    # assert square bracket after
          /$1/eex;   # double evaluate the variable
```

The double evaluation is necessary, as the first evaluation turns the variable into a string, and then the string is evaluated.

Although you will run into trouble with `10^2`, as `^` is the binary XOR operator, not the exponentiation operator `**`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way: `$line =~ s/.*?\[(.*?)\]/$1/ge`

Comment: This will replace the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Miguel is right:

```
my $string =
q|int a[100];
int b[10*10];
int c[10*5+(25*2)];
int d[10^2];|;

foreach my $line (split(/\n/,$string)) {
        if ($line =~ m/\[([^\]]+)\]/) {
                my $equation = $1;
                my $val = eval($equation);
                # escape out the special characters.
                $equation =~ s/\*/\\\*/g;
                $equation =~ s/\,/\\\,/g;
                $equation =~ s/\+/\\\+/g;
                $equation =~ s/\)/\\\)/g;
                $equation =~ s/\(/\\\(/g;
                $equation =~ s/\^/\\\^/g;

                $line =~ s/\[$equation\]/\[$val\]/;
        }
        print "$line\n";
}
```

This returns:

```
int a[100];
int b[100];
int c[100];
int d[8];
```

So you see you'll also need to alter the special character for "power of".
But I think this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use `quotemeta` to sanitize your replacement string:

```
if ( $line =~ m/.*?\[(.*?)\]/ ) {
    my $expr = quotemeta($1);
    my $answer = eval ($1);
    $line =~ s/$expr/$answer/;
}
```